# How to open file object from 'os' using 'with'?

Tags: python, subprocess, fdopen

I'm trying to open file using 'os.open()' as below

```
>>> filePath
'C:\\Shashidhar\\text.csv'
>>> fd = os.open(filePath,os.O_CREAT)
>>> with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as myfile:
...    myfile.write("hello")

IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

>>>
```

Any idea how can I open the file object from os.fdopen using "with" so that connection can be closed automatially?

Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to open a file this way and not with the standard `open()` or even, `io.open()`?

Comment: I have set os.nice(19) before that. And I would like to make use of os to create and open files so that I will have "niceness" while performing this operations!

Comment: @Shashi. I don't understand. What has `os.nice` to do with `os.open`?

Answer (score 3):

use this form, it worked.

```
with os.fdopen(os.open(filepath,os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR ),'w') as fd:  
    fd.write("abcd")
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on [Rohith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19587517/296974), they way you are opening the file is important.

The `with` works by internally calling seleral functions, so I tried it out step by step:

```
>>> fd = os.open("c:\\temp\\xyxy", os.O_CREAT)
>>> f = os.fdopen(fd, 'w')
>>> myfile = f.__enter__()
>>> myfile.write("213")
>>> f.__exit__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

What? Why? And why now?

If I do the same with

```
>>> fd = os.open(filepath, os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR)
```

all works fine.

With `write()` you only wrote to the file object's output puffer, and `f.__exit__()` essentiall calls `f.close()`, which in turn calls `f.flush()`, which flushes this output buffer to disk - or, at least, tries to do so.

But it fails, as the file is not writable. So a `[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` occurs.