# python os module raise errors other than OSError?

Tags: python

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

"Note All functions in this module raise OSError in the case of invalid or inaccessible file names and paths, or other arguments that have the correct type, but are not accepted by the operating system."

So all functions that starts with os. in front of them i.e. (os.chown and os.listdir) will only raise OSError?

Are there any cases where they would raise other errors such as IOError or whatnot? If so, could you give me some example?

P.S. I am asking this question because the website lists "some" cases but I am not sure if these "some" are the only cases associated with the os module.

Comment: More about OSError : http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html I see error attributes changes for different types of OSErrors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSError will only be raised, as quoted, "in the case of invalid or inaccessible file names and paths, or other arguments that have the correct type, but are not accepted by the operating system."

So, for example, try `os.chdir(42)`

```
>>> os.chdir(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be string, not int
```

TypeError - because the argument doesn't have the correct type (`...other arguments that have the correct type...`)

OSError means that the arguments were not accepted *by the Operating System*

So the answer is yes, `os` can raise other types of errors.

Comment: could you think of a case where it could raise IOError specifically?

Comment: @ealeon see the other answers for examples of this

Answer (score 2):

`IOError` is possible if there is a problem accessing the location - like someone unplugged the USB drive

`MemoryError` can pop up nearly anywhere if you run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

check this link, [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557513/how-to-open-file-object-from-os-using-with/19587517#19587517) , here it gives IOError, even if you dont use with-as construct.
these error types or exceptions indicate the type of problem that is reason for the call failure.so different types of exceptions are posible.even with os module methods.they throw exceptions to indicate the type of problem.so may not be OSError only.